# Print JasperReports client-side?

Tags: reporting, jasper-reports

I have developed a web application that uses JasperReports. I noticed that the reports are printing server-side.

How do you make the reports print client-side (from the web browser)?

Any insights will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have a Servlets-based architecture:

1. Get a handle on the `HttpServletResponse` instance with `HttpServletResponse response = this.getThreadLocalResponse();` (for instance).
2. Set the various headers to indicate a file attachment.

   ```
   HttpServletResponse response = getServletResponse();
   response.setHeader( "Content-Description", "File Transfer" );
   response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +
     "report.pdf" );
   response.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/pdf" );
   response.setHeader( "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary" );
   ```
3. Configure the `JRExporter` (jre) to use the HttpServletRespone's output stream:

   ```
       jre.setParameter( JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, getOutputStream() );
   ```
4. Execute the report.

The browser will prompt the user to save the report as a PDF file. The user can print the PDF.